# how can i reverse a list in python for example l=[12,51,32]. I want the expected output to be l=[21,15,23]?

Tags: python, string, list, integer, reverse

I know reverse() is used to reverse a list but i want each element inside the list to be reverse
ususally if
l=[21,35,56]
then
l.reverse()
output is
[56,35,21]

but I want the output as [12,53,65]

Comment: `[int(reversed(str(e))) for e in l]`

Comment: What should be the output is one of the elements ends in a 0?

Comment: what should be the output it the number is negative, i.e. `-100` ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert each integer to string, reverse the string using [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509415/967621), convert it back to integer. Everything is wrapped in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l = [21, 35, 56]
lst = [int(str(x)[::-1]) for x in l]
print(lst)
# [12, 53, 65]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [21, 35, 56]
result = [int(str(i)[::-1]) for i in data]
print(result)
>>> [12, 53, 65]
```